# How to instantiate a subclass with Dozer?

Tags: java, dozer

I have following *target* classes:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    private String postion;
    ...
}

public class PersonContainer {
   private Person person;
   ...
}
```

And this is my source:

```
public class Form {
    private String firstNameEmployee;
    private String lastNameEmployee;
    private String positionEmployee;
    ...
}
```

#### GOAL

I would like to get object *PersonContainer* but not with *Person* object but with *Employee* object. I really have no idea how to achieve that. How to tell Dozer to instantiate a subclass?

This mapping gives *Person* object:

```xml
 <mapping>
    <class-a>hl.test.dozer03.form.Form</class-a>
    <class-b>hl.test.dozer03.result.PersonContainer</class-b>


    <field>
        <a>firstNameEmployee</a>
        <b>person.firstName</b>
    </field>

    <field>
        <a>lastNameEmployee</a>
        <b>person.lastName</b>
    </field>

 </mapping>
```

Can this be done by slightly modifying this *mapping*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom-createMethod. http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customCreateMethod.html

Something like this:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>hl.test.dozer03.form.Form</class-a>
  <class-b create- method="PersonContainerFactory.createPersonContainer">hl.test.dozer03.result.PersonContainer</class-b>


  <field>
    <a>firstNameEmployee</a>
    <b>person.firstName</b>
  </field>

  <field>
    <a>lastNameEmployee</a>
    <b>person.lastName</b>
  </field>

</mapping>
```

With the java class:

```
public class PersonContainerFactory {

  public static PersonContainer createPersonContainer(){
      PersonContainer cont = new PersonContainer();
      cont.setPerson(new Employee());
      return classA;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine. Just one thing: do you know how to set value for Employee.position? <b>person.position</b> does not work since type of field PersonContainer.person is Person.

Comment: You could do something similar with a custom-converter on the field mapping. <field custom-converter-id="CustomConverter"><a>field1</a><b>field2</b></field> And have the CustomConverter work out if the target object is employee, if so, cast it and set the value. http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Person class fields to protected so they can be inherited

```
public class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    ...
}
```

Change from PersonContainer to (what it is you want)

```
public class EmployeeContainer {
   private Employee employee;
   ...
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: unfortunatelly changing from PersonContainer to EmployeeContainer is not the way. This is simple example of more complex problem. The main thing here is to instantiate subclass Employee and put it in superclass field.